# Referring ActiveX Combobox from Module

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to refer ActiveX ComboBox value from module. I put ComboBox which named ComboBox1 into worksheet. This worksheet names is "Setup Sheet" and code name "SetupSheet". And i want to read value of combo box from my module named SettingsModule.

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup Sheet").ComboBox1.Value
```

but it gives an error `Method or Object not found.`

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use your [worksheet's **codename**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel).

This is different from the sheet name as well as the sheet index, so if you are not familiar with codenames at all you might want to read up on it.

In the VBE project explorer, you will see your codenames followed by your sheet names, and it would look something like `Sheet1 (Setup Sheet)`.

Assuming your *Setup Sheet's* codename is `Sheet1`, then you could simply use

```
Sheet1.Combobox1.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `.ComboBox1.Value` with `Shapes("ComboBox1").DrawingObject.Object.Value`